# Why can't "Qui est ton actrice préférée" be written as "Ton actrice préférée est qui"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, conjugaison, questions

> Qui est ton actrice préférée ?

Is a correct question in French, but, to me,

> Ton actrice préférée est qui ?

is also following French rules.
What is wrong with the latter form?

Comment: Why do you think it can't?

Comment: Isn't a question mark missing after *est qui*?

Comment: and after *wrong*?

Answer (score 5):

“Qui est ton actrice préférée ?” is correct and idiomatic formal or neutral French.

“Ton actrice préférée est qui ?” is correct according to the rules of informal French, but not really idiomatic. It's awkward because when we ask an open question, we like to have the question word near the beginning. (In formal French, it has to be at the beginning.) So we'd rather ask “Ton actrice préférée, c'est qui ?” or “C'est qui, ton actrice préférée ?”, splitting the sentence into a context part (not interrogative) and a short interrogative part. Either order works in this case.

Additionally, I think the formulation of the question suggests that “ton actrice préférée” is already known in some way, but there's still a question about her identity in some context. Maybe when asking which actress in a specific movie is your favorite? Or when the name of the actrice has just been said and we want to express surprise by asking for confirmation? I don't perceive this awkwardness with other formulations like “Ton actrice préférée, c'est qui ?”.

Answer (score 0):

«est qui ?» at end of question is not really proper grammar.
It also doesn’t sound well. It could better be :

> C’est qui ton actrice préférée ?

Comment: *Ton actrice préférée, c'est qui?*  would equally work and *Ton actrice préférée est qui ?* would be a perfect reply by someone who didn't understand the name just given.